Xamarin android app crashes when app on the background
I downloaded my release on the device with the lates version of Xamarin forms and linking = none.
App works good, but when I using other app and getting back to my Xamarin app(it was on the background while I had been using other apps) it crashes without any reasons. After restarting of the app it works perfect again. It happens on all android devices. Have you ever had this problem? What should I try to fix it?
Tried to set other linking, rebuild, update Xamarin packages, but it didn't helps

You need to add logging and/or crash reporting tools to figure out what the cause is

@Jason I can't get this on release mode.

I have no idea what you mean.  There are plenty of tools that will work in release mode.  Or you can just use simple console logging and view it with adb

@Jason i cant reproduce this error on adb, probably error happens because of battery saving mode on my device

If you trun off  battery saving mode, will it work well?
